# How do I answer this?

Tags: cipher, pattern, calculation-puzzle

So, I'm trying to figure out this weird code that was sent from one of my friends. Could someone please tell me the sentence within?

30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20

30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20

30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 31 30 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 20 30 30 31 31 30 31 30 31

Comment: I think you could use online decoders for this

Comment: It might be a good idea to also show us the original puzzle.

Comment: Okay, I will show the original puzzle. It's extremely long though.

Comment: Ohhh...that's fair.- my bad. Perhaps it _should_ be left out.

Comment: Should I just put in the binary part so it would be a tad shorter?

Comment: Was this puzzle _created_ by the friend who sent it to you?

Comment: I'm not sure, he sent it to me and he seems pretty smart.

Comment: Did he just send it with no context, or did he say anything about it?

Comment: (Also, the solution to this contains what appears to be personal information - are you sure this is something you should be sharing?)

Comment: The riddle itself is a good riddle for beginners. The solution to it should do no personal harm to the user.

Answer (score 2):

As you already edited out, this is Hex Coded binary.
$30_{16}$ is $0_{ascii}$
$31_{16}$ is $1_{ascii}$
$20_{16}$ is $Space_{ascii}$

When decoded, the binary numbers are 8 bit, separated by spaces. The Values are
$00100000_{2}$ is $Space_{ascii}$
$00110000_{2}$ is $0_{ascii}$
$00110100_{2}$ is $4_{ascii}$
...

Wenn decoded, the text looks like this
055 056 056 040 055 055 040 040 040 040 040 055 055 040 056 040 040 040 040 040 056 055 040 055 040 040 040 040 040 056 055 040 055 056 056 040 056 055 040 055 055 040 055 040 056 055 040 055 056 055 056 040 055 040 056 056 040 055 056 055 056 040 056 055 040 056 055 056 056 040 055 055 055 055 055 040 055 055 055 055 055 040 055 055 055 055 055 040 056 055 055 055 055

Now, this you already posted.

This are

> Octal numbers
>  $055_{8}$ is $-_{ascii}$
>  $056_{8}$ is $._{ascii}$
>  $040_{8}$ is $Space_{ascii}$

Which gives

> Morse code
>  One Space is letter separater, four spaces are word separater, i replaced it with /
>  -.. -- / -- . / .- - / .- -.. .- -- - .- -.-. - .. -.-. .- .-.. ----- ----- ----- .----

Which decodes as

> DM ME AT ADAMTACTICAL0001